# Is "fittest" as in "survival of the fittest" still used this way today?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

Can "fittest" still be used to say "the most fitting", just like in the set phrase "survival of the fittest" that was written by Charles Darwin quite some time ago? Or does it only mean "the most fit", meaning "the most sportive"? Thanks!

Comment: Darwin used "fittest" to mean best adapted to requirements or conditions.  Today, we commonly use "best fit" for the task, job, or whatever to mean the same.  We use "fittest" to describe someone in the best physical condition, which might be the modern equivalent of a characteristic likely to lead to success and reproduction (I'm not sure that usage of "fit" is totally unrelated).  We don't commonly refer to a an item that is the "best fit" as the "fittest".  But Darwin's usage is not so old that it is no longer understood, and doesn't even sound strange, although it isn't in common use now.

Comment: @fixer1234 Thanks so much! That's the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fitness described by Darwin, also known as Darwinian fitness, is used in the biological sense:

> A relative measure of reproductive success of an organism in passing its genes to the next generation.

Source: http://www.biology-online.org/dictionary/Fitness

Although the common meaning of fitness today is related to Darwinian fitness, Darwinian fitness is not related to being "the most sportive" or anything of the like (unless being "the most sportive" results in a chance to produce more offspring).

---

OP follow-up comment:

> So the sentence "I think this bag is the fittest for our car" to say that the bag fits the most inti our car is incorrect then, because a bag is no living creature at all, is that correct? And is fitness still used the way darwin used it?

The most common meaning of fitness today is the fitness you are talking about. If you are talking about Darwinian fitness, you should probably use the phrase "Darwinian fitness" to specify it. So if the sentence does not specify it is talking about Darwinian fitness, your example sentence is fine.

Comment: So the sentence "I think this bag is the fittest for our car" to say that the bag fits the most inti our car is incorrect then, because a bag is no living creature at all, is that correct? And is fitness still used the way darwin used it?

Comment: @Nearoo I edited my post to address that.

Comment: @Nearoo No problem :)

Comment: @ʇolɐǝzǝɥʇqoq I cannot possibly accept that "This bag is the fittest for our car" is idiomatic. Is that what you were saying? Used in that sense it should be "this bag is the most fitting...", "This wallpaper is the most fitting for our drawing room".

Comment: Yeah, that's the question: Would that be possible. So should I not use it?